# Return the "extended" length of a String

Tags: java, string, unicode, unicode-string, string-length

For Unicode characters, such as this No-Break Space ] [ of ASCII code 160, generated by holding the Alt key *and* typing 160 in the numpad, it yields a length of two characters.

For example, I have a field (e.g. the Tag field in Android log) of 88 characters. If I have 87 normal characters (ASCII < 127) and one No-Break Space, in `String.length()` I will still get 88. But in fact it needs a length of 89. And it exceeds the field size.

Is there a function in Java (or Android), that simply returns the "extended" length of a string?

FYI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Comment: Do you mean something like `String#getBytes("UTF-8").length`?

Comment: There is no such thing as ASCII code 160. ASCII range is 00-127.

Comment: @dda - This can happen if you're reading from a document. No break character is also fetched - ASCII 160. Kindly read this - http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: ASCII does not have anything over 127... 0xA0 as an unbreakable space is CP 1252 codepage http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT

Comment: Hmmm... as i read from the wiki/utf-8, in fact 160 is using 2 bytes to represent. So, somehow, that 160-no-break-space is like sticking 2 ordinary characters together. If strictly reading byte-by-byte, those 2 bytes doesn't make sense at all. However, if the program is set to UTF-8 mode, it will read 160 as a whole when it encounters. (i guess that's just a naming issue of ASCII or not.)

Answer (score 1):

Your mental model of Java characters is confused. That string has 88 *characters*, which when written out as a UTF-8 sequence need 89 *bytes*. Which version you will need to use depends on what you want to do with it, obviously. If you're going to use a network link to send data, you will need to use octets (bytes).

Comment: I was a little confused by this as well, until I read Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot's comment (great name, BTW)